# document.getElementById works but document.getElementsByTagName does not work

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

To select all the p tag inside div - it works with `document.getElementById()` but not with `document.getElementsByTagName()`. Why is that?

```
<div id="myDIV">
   <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example" in div</h2>
   <p>Para 1 first</p> 
   <p>Para 2</p> 
   <p>Para 3</p> 
   <p>Para 4</p> 
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

This works

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV").querySelectorAll("p");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

This does not

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div").querySelectorAll("p");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` returns collection but not a single Node so you can't use `querySelector` on it.

Comment: You're mixing up solutions, which makes an unfair comparison. `document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("p");` should work.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.     function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].querySelectorAll("p");
        var i;
       for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

Comment: when I declared the array it works with tagname also. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of direct selector like :

```
document.querySelectorAll("#myDIV p");
//Or
document.querySelectorAll("div p");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div p");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
   <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example" in div</h2>
   <p>Para 1 first</p> 
   <p>Para 2</p> 
   <p>Para 3</p> 
   <p>Para 4</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: It says - cannot set backgroundColor of undefined

Comment: Where? have you tried my snippet?

Comment: I meant if you use document.querySelectorAll("div p"); it will give the undefined error

Comment: Now it works.. i guess i had made an error. Thank you, so i learnt two ways to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">



</head>

<body>
<div id="myDIV">
   <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example" in div</h2>
   <p>Para 1 first</p> 
   <p>Para 2</p> 
   <p>Para 3</p> 
   <p>Para 4</p> 
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```